# Mutliple "bridge" lines in torrc

Tags: configuration, bridge

Using Tor (not the TBB), therefore I must compose my torrc config files manually. Using bridges that I get from "bridges.torproject.org".
Assume the "torrc" in use has *more than one* 'Bridge' lines in it, my question is: does *tor* try the Bridges in order until one is found which answers the (whatever) protocol handshake, or will it try only one and stall, ignoring extra 'Bridge' lines, in case the first specified bridge is down or otherwise *kaput* ?

In other words, while the torproject site will usually give me 3 bridges at a time to try from, is it any useful to have the 3 of them at the same time, as 3 successive torrc lines, or should I select just one at a time, removing/replacing a nonworking's bridge line ?

Unable to check how the TBB manages "its" torrc since I don't use that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will try successive bridges until it is able to use one, starting with the first bridge listed in the `torrc`.

So it can be helpful to use multiple bridge lines, incase one bridge goes down or is censored or blocked.

This behaviour will change with `tor-3.0.x` *(slightly)* in that it won't try them in the order presented.